# De-Interlace footage in Avid Media Composer using standard effects

Tags: video, avid

What's the best way to De-Interlace footage in Avid Media Composer using fairly standard effects?  Assume the project media format and footage are interlaced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Timewarp** motion effect (adjusted with the Motion Effect Editor) can be used to deinterlace with the following settings:

- Type: **Both Fields**
- Source: **Interlaced**
- Check **Adaptive Deinterlace Source**
- Output: **Progressive**

[image]

Source: http://community.avid.com/forums/p/99392/572313.aspx